# Best hashing algorithm for file detection

Tags: php, md5, checksum

I want to be able to validate a large quantity of files (a couple of TB) on a semi regular basis via PHP.  Security is not an issue and collisions isn't a particularly big one either since it also factors in filesizes.  The main goal is to generate the hashes quickly and with as little CPU as possible.

My current candidate is md5_file() but was wondering if there is another approach that could be more efficient?

Comment: You're probably limited by disk IO, so I would guess that the algorithm choice doesn't matter... (although I haven't checked!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If efficiency is an issue and security is not, how about simply the binary XOR of the files?  Much faster.

Comment: Is it?  I could understand it being faster if the data was already in memory, but we're reading data from disk here...

Comment: Any kind of hash would necessitate *reading the data*.  MD5 (or any other strong hash) would add CPU cost on top of that.

Comment: Most of the CPU time will happen in parallel with the disk access (in a sensible implementation).  I don't know whether `md5_file` is a sensible implementation...

Comment: Maybe it would, but the question was about minimizing CPU time.  If (as seems plausible) the real problem is minimizing clock time in an environment where these terabytes of data are on physical hard-drives, yes, the cost of hashing is probably negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PHP for such things. Use dedicated tools such as [Tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/).

Answer (score -1):

I think that **sha1** could be your best bet, in php you'd use **sha1_file**

Comment: your task is more io bound so I don't see why to loose the little you would gain processing the slightly slower sha1. I don't know however if you need that cpu resources for higher priority tasks